# html table id's are dynamic in nature for me to filter data based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm new to html & js. I'm leveraging render() function in python to convert a dataframe to html where I'm trying to add dropdown to the page. once the html page is generated, i'm finding table id to be randomly generated unique value for me to use it in javascript logic for dropdown to filter html data. Kindly could someone help me how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Is this django? Please add the appropriate tag and include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

While rendering pass the parameter, table_id="Your_id", to the dataframe.to_html function, 
Ex:

DataFrame.to_html(table_id="Your_id").

Also the following is a good link to look over:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Here is a good github reference to the source code:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L1977-L2040

Comment: after using this method, I'm finding two ids while rendering html file. one id has dynamic & unique value, other id is showing "myTable". probably because we have two ids in table tag - this is not allowing my function to filter data.